# Unable to import pydantic in lambda function

Tags: python, aws-lambda, pydantic, aws-lambda-layers

I am trying to import pydantic to a lambda via a lambda layer

and I keep getting this error

[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'main': No module named 'pydantic' Traceback (most recent call last):

The lambda uses python 3.9,Architecture x86_64, I have tried these commands separately :

- docker run -i -v $(pwd)/layer:/app -w /app --entrypoint /bin/bash public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9 -c "pip3 install --target ./python -r requirements.txt"
- pip3 install --target layer/python -r requirements.txt --upgrade
- docker run -i -v $(pwd)/layer:/app -w /app --user $(id -u):$(id -g) --entrypoint /bin/bash python:3.10.13-slim-bullseye -c "pip3 install --target ./python -r requirements.txt --upgrade"
- pip install -r requirements.txt --python-version 3.9 --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 --target layer/python --only-binary=:all:

and then compress the packages zip -r layer.zip layer/python and upload the layer and import it in the lambda

and I keep getting this error

[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'main': No module named 'pydantic' Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: `python -m pip install pydantic`

Comment: Are there any `pydantic` in `requirements.txt`?

Comment: Please provide the requirements.txt and the code snippet where you perform these imports.

Comment: using this fixed the issue with updating the lambda python version to 3.9 
`pip install -r requirements.txt --python-version 3.9 --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 --target layer/python --only-binary=:all:`

as well as using a zip file that includes only python directory instead of layer/python

Answer (score 1):

The following fixed the issue

1. using `pip install -r requirements.txt --python-version 3.9 --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 --target layer/python --only-binary=:all:`
2. make sure that the lambda python version is 3.9
3. when creating the zip file it should be python/pydantic so it can be imported from the layer correctly